# Why org.springFramework.Boot.loader.jar.JarFile causes memory leak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, skywalking

When using Skywalking, the Eclipse MAT shows that **JarFile and JarFileWrapper consume a lot of memory and continue to grow**.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, **Jarfile has risen from 184m to 469m，And there are more and more objects**.

[image]

And the GC ROOTS contains:

- org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalThread
- com.dianping.cat.util.Threads$RunnableThread
- java.lang.Thread
- java.lang.ref.Finalizer
- java.lang.Thread

How do I find the root cause of the problem?

Version Info:

- Skywalking: 8.2.0
- SpringBoot: 2.3.3-RELEASE

Comment: What does Retained Heap signify?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Retained heap is the amount of memory that will be freed when the particular object is garbage collected.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue in the meantime? I am facing the same issue with (at least) one of our SB services. Which SB version are you using? This SB issue report here states that they started seeing possibly the same issue starting with 2.7.1. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32071